# How to dynamically specify a column in stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I need to write a stored procedure which will update into a particular column, based on parameters. This will be called from a C# app.

The table to be updated is like this:

TableA: Id, Col1, Col2, Col3.

Something like this:

```
Create Procedure UpdateByCol
 @col_num int,
 @value string,
 @id int
as
Begin
    Update TableA Set *How do I specify the column here* = @value where Id = @id
End
```

Comment: Why do you want this? Serious code smell.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it's the existing design and I can't change it.

Comment: Stored procedures weren't designed to do this well. This can't really be compiled, you could do an evaluation of the SQL you want, but then you lose the benefits of stored procedures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max)

Set @SQL = 'Update ' + @TableName + ' Set ' + @Col1 + ' = ' + @Col1Val....

Exec (@SQL)
```

This exposes you to SQL injection though...

Comment: also, you might be interested in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20815/Building-Dynamic-SQL-In-a-Stored-Procedure

Comment: Ick.  Might as well just use dynamically generated SQL outside of a stored procedure.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yeah, but the problem is ick, so pick your poison.

Comment: If you wanted to patch the injection vulnerabilities, you could though. It would be recommended.

Comment: I realize I could use sql pass through from C# to do the same thing, but it seems that it is not really any safer than doing it through a stored procedure.  In this case, the SP is just taking an int to indicate the column, so I don't see how Sql Injection could occur.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this without dynamic sql.  Create individual stored procs for each column that is eligible for updating.  Then, in your master stored proc, call the applicable stored proc based on the paramter received.

Answer (score 0):

It is not good practice to do this but if you really wanted to you'd have to use dynamic sql to create the string and execute it like so:

```
Create Procedure UpdateByCol
 @col_num int,
 @value string,
 @id int
as
Begin
    declare @str varchar(2000)
    set @str = 'Update TableA Set Col' + convert(varchar,@col) + ' = ''' + @value + ''' where Id = ' + convert(varchar, @id )

    exec ( @str )
End
```

This is a **very bad** thing to do because it creates a security hole.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this it can be done with dynamic sql. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx